# Python multiprocessing.Pool outputs nothing to file

Tags: python, file-io, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


f = open("./testing.txt", "a")


def predefined_fp(s: str):
    '''
    This function doesn't actually write anything to file.
    '''
    # Example output to console from below:
    # writing 13 to <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./testing.txt' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
    print(f"writing {s} to {f}")
    f.write(s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    should_be_empty = pool.map(predefined_fp, [str(i) for i in range(16)], 2)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    f.flush() # Not having this doesn't change results
    f.close() # Not having this doesn't change results
```

While I was trying to understand how the Python `multiprocessing.Pool` plays with FileIO, I ran into a situation that I just could not understand.

Running the above code creates the file `testing.txt`, but the file contents are empty.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it had nothing to do w/ multiprocessing.
FileIO only actually outputs to file on `.flush()`.

Hence flushing fixes the problem.

**Before:**

```
def predefined_fp(s: str):
    f.write(s)
```

**After:**

```
def predefined_fp(s: str):
    f.write(s)
    f.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open and call append function of file when you want to append the data on it.
So use that inside your function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def predefined_fp(s: str):

    f = open("./testing.txt", "a")
'''
This function doesn't actually write anything to file.
'''
# Example output to console from below:
# writing 13 to <_io.TextIOWrapper name='./testing.txt' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
    print(f"writing {s} to {f}")
    f.write(s)
    f.flush()
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(4)
    should_be_empty = pool.map(predefined_fp, [str(i) for i in range(16)], 2)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Alternative method:-

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def predefined_fp(s: str):
    with open("./testing.txt", "a") as f:
        print(f"writing {s} to {f}")
        f.write(s)
        f.write('\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(4) as p:
        should_be_empty = p.map(predefined_fp, [str(i) for i in range(16)], 2)
```

Comment: I see thanks. But do you know why the first one doesn't work?